# Binary XML file line #15: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030003 a=-1}

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was building up a calculator app on Android Studio. When I ran the app on Android  Pie device, the following fatal error occurred. As I am new to Android development, I didn't carry on as soon as the error occurred, the main function of the calculator isn't included in the java file.

[logcat]

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030003 a=-1}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030003 a=-1}
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030003 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7767)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7958)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1997)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:743)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.generateLayoutParams(AppBarLayout.java:366)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.generateLayoutParams(AppBarLayout.java:110)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
    at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

and in main activity,

```
    package com.example.calculator;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.calculator.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private double valueOne, valueTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//
//        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });
        // Mr. Rigby
        // Steven, test

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and what's in the corresponding activity_main.xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

and finally what's in content_main.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_plus"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="@string/button_plus"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_minus"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb_valueA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_minus"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="@string/button_minus"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_multiply"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_plus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb_valueA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_multiply"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="@string/button_multiply"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bt_divide"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_minus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb_valueB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_divide"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="@string/button_divide"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_multiply"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb_valueB" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tb_valueA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="158dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:hint="@string/valueA"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/valueA"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tb_valueB"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tb_valueB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="158dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:hint="@string/valueB"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/valueB"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tb_valueA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="206dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.222"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_multiply"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.962" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Line number 15 in the content_main.xml showing problem. try changing  android:layout_width="0dp"to  android:layout_width="100dp" //something else and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: The problem still with the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

Your layout file can not find ?attr/actionBarSize.

To get action bar size in AppCompat:

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

Or you can set manually:

```
56dp (default)
48dp (landscape)
64dp (sw600dp; i.e. tablet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but you should check your app theme in your styles.xml file. If you have changed it, you have changed it to one that is not compatible with your activity which from what I can see, seems to be a "basic activity" format.

Try changing it to one that descends from Theme.AppCompat for starters. Also, don't forget the define this too and use it on your activity in the android manifest

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

As for a fix that allows you to keep your theme and solve the problem. I will get back to you on that.